# Function like enumerate to get index and value for offset arrays?

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

If I have an array like this:

```
using OffsetArrays

a = OffsetArray(collect(1:5),(11:15))
```

I can iterate through the array with:

```
for (i,x) in enumerate(a)
    println((i,x))
end
```

and get:

```
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
```

But I want this:

```
(11, 1)
(12, 2)
(13, 3)
(14, 4)
(15, 5)
```

**Is there a way to get the real index since I am using an offset array?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `pairs` respects the indexing behaviour:

```
julia> using OffsetArrays

julia> a = OffsetArray(collect(1:5),(11:15))

julia> for (i,x) in pairs(a)
         println((i,x))
       end

(11, 1)
(12, 2)
(13, 3)
(14, 4)
(15, 5)
```

[from the docs:](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs)

> `Base.pairs` — *Function*.
>
> `pairs(collection)`
>
> Return an iterator over `key => value` pairs for any collection that maps a set of keys to a set of values. This includes arrays, where the keys are the array indices.
>
> ```
> pairs(IndexLinear(), A)
> pairs(IndexCartesian(), A)
> pairs(IndexStyle(A), A)
> ```
>
> An iterator that accesses each element of the array `A`, returning `i => x`, where `i` is the index for the element and `x = A[i]`. Identical to `pairs(A)`, except that the style of index can be selected. Also similar to `enumerate(A)`, except `i` will be a valid index for `A`, while `enumerate` always counts from 1 regardless of the indices of `A`.
>
> Specifying `IndexLinear()` ensures that `i` will be an integer; specifying `IndexCartesian()` ensures that `i` will be a `CartesianIndex`; specifying `IndexStyle(A)` chooses whichever has been defined as the native indexing style for array `A`.
>
> Mutation of the bounds of the underlying array will invalidate this iterator.